# I have cisco asa 5508 and setup as dhcp for 4 networks segments and 3 servers connected to dmz ,the asa 5508 is working for a while then stop

Tags: routing

I try to use asa 5508 on my network with 480 workstations.I connect interface1(192.168.1.0/24) to a swith with 3 linux servers,interface 2( (192.168.3.0/24) to a 48 manged switch, interface 3 (192.168.4.0/24) and interface 4(192.168.4.0/24) and interface 5 (192.168.5.0/24),Of course each segment has swith and ap connected to it.ASA 5508 act as dhcp server in each segment.It works for a day or so, then stop no one can access to the internet nor the server.My question is :Is it the right way to use asa 5508 as dhcp server for 480 clients? Can I use my linux server on dmz to be a main dhcp server for the other interfaces? Thanks for your help!!

Comment: you don't have anything in ASA's logs? do you run the latest ASA software?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can and it would be better to use a DHCP Linux server for your entire network. I would place it in your Linux DMZ/interface 1.

Keep in mind that as DHCP was designed as a network broadcast domain protocol, the DHCP requests have to be forwarded to your DHCP server; at the moment you have a different design, which is known as a multi homed DHCP server.

As such you have to configure DHCP relaying in each network. DHCP relaying will forward DHCP requests from each network to the specified DHCP server.

[ASA DHCP Relay Configuration Example](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/adaptive-security-appliance-asa-software/116265-configure-product-00.html)

I would also start planning the future evolution and data usage of your network (in 2-3 years time, maybe sooner). Albeit the theoretical backplane of the 5508 is 8Gbps, depending on the firewall and NAT rules, often with ASA equipments, the speed the backbone withstands can get to half of that.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, I will try this asap and see if it solve my issues.